# Gradle error while generating signingReport

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to generate SHA256 fingerprint of my app to use firebase but getting the following error as 'bundle' not found!

```
Task 'gradle' not found in root project 'AquF' and its subprojects. Some candidates are: 'bundle'.

* Try:
> Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
> For more on name expansion, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:name_abbreviation in the Gradle documentation.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 162ms
```

Help me in generating the fingerprint as firebase is not authorising the auth request!